# What is the best way to handle dynamic Iframe values in BluePrism

Tags: blueprism, spy

i am working on a progress, but it always crashes when i use the HTML spy. the reason i found out is that the iframe is changing. Is there a way to make it dynamic, so it reads and gets the iframe. so that i can add it into a dataitem and add it into the dynamic spy.

1 time it runs : /HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(6)/DIV(1)/IFRAME(2)/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(3)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)

2 time: 
/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(6)/DIV(1)/IFRAME(5)/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(3)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)

3 time: /HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(6)/DIV(1)/IFRAME(3)/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(3)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spy the iFrame if possible, capture the path in a variable, 
use Dynamic path for all elements by prefixing it with the iFrame Path.

if this does not work let me know and I can give you another option.